# Save code present in string (strhtmlbody) as HTML file in ADLS (Azure Data Lake Store ) path using Python -Databricks

Tags: python, azure, scala

**Method 1:**

To create new HTML file in ADLS path ,tried below code and it is not creating any file in the specified path and also not giving any error.

```
token=lib.auth(tenant_id='ddb8592f-ed74-4329-bfd2-571b7c34699e',client_secret='6J+HpWerwedO1ZzKZBDxxgpQHLr75QQaG2Kvv/da7jRzyg8=',client_id='0f081437-f82er4-4f10-944d-92f0detwewb6bc37b')
    adls_client=core.AzureDLFileSystem(token,store_name='adlsedhdev')
    strFormat='Results_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'    
    strFileName= datetime.now().strftime(strFormat)

#creating a new html file for every run 
strResultFilePath='/mnt/adlsedhdev/DEV/Result'+ strFileName + '.html'
with adls_client.open(strResultFilePath,'wb') as f:
    #"strhtmlbody" is a string variable which has HTML code
    f.write(str.encode(strhtmlbody))
    f.flush()
    f.close()
```

**Method 2:

Using below spark code,  it is working fine but saving as text file instead of HTML file.

```
#"strhtmlbody" is a string variable which has HTML code
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([strhtmlbody])
 rdd.repartition(1).coalesce(1).overwrite().saveAsTextFile('/mnt/adlsedhdev/DEV/Result')
```

Can someone help me to fix the issue?